# Generate custom start and end date series in postgresql and sum qty for a given billing cycle

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql arena and have stumbled into new problem of summing up subscription_qty for each month starting from subscribe_start_date's month and ending in current's month

```
given table is

account_id.  |. subscribe_start_date.      |   subscription_qty
123               2021-01-29 00:00:00.0           26
112               2021-10-27 00:00:00.0           261
---

now() i.e. today's date is 10/07/2021.
```

I've looked into `generate_series() function and it does the job but date values are fixed and it fails to handle following edge cases (which is expected)

Pseudo logic is as following:

```
 - if subscription_date is between 1 and 28 then month-to-month cycle works great but
 - if subscription_date is 29, 30 or 31 then there are two issues
   - 1st issue: feb month is of 29 in leap year and if we just consider 2021 which has 28 days in feb then if subscription_date was 2021-01-29 00:00:00.0 then next billing date will be 2021-02-28 00:00:00.0 but then march will become 2021-01-29 00:00:00.0 again and it will continue.
  - 2nd issue: if day of subscription_date is 2021-01-31 00:00:00.0 then we have months of 30 and feb issue as listed above.
```

I was thinking of generating `start_date` and `end_date` using `cte` and then use it in main query `to sum(subscription_qty) where usage_date >=start_date and usage_date<=end_date`. Can someone please suggest if generating start and end_date in sub_query is good idea and how we can do it while accounting for edge cases. Is it good approach and also can you please share sample code to generate start_date and end_date column range for monthly billing cycle from subscription_start_date till now. sample could be:

```
account_id.  |. subscribe_start_date.      |   start_date.   | end date
123               2021-01-29 00:00:00.0        2021-01-29.     2021-02-28
123               2021-01-29 00:00:00.0        2021-03-01.     2021-03-31
...
...
123               2021-01-29 00:00:00.0        2021-09-01.     2021-09-30
123               2021-01-29 00:00:00.0        2021-10-01.     2021-10-31
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar is messy with months of varying days between the and even within the same month (Feb). Fortunately Postgres is aware of the irregularities (almost always). So work with it, let Postgres take care of them. With intervals of `1 month` and `1 day` can you  make the irregularity of Feb and the 30/31 days per months simply disappear.  

The first start_date is the subscription_date and its end date is the end of the start_date month or the end of following month. From there every thing follows a specific pattern: start_date is prior end_date + 1 day, end_date is the last day of that month. The issue in determining the last day of the month. But this is simply done: Truncate the Start_Date to the Month add 1 Month and subtract 1 day. Note this totally ignores the actual month and the number of days within it. You then wrap all that in a recursive CTE which steps from from 1 row to the next (iteratively). As follows:

```
with recursive billing( account_id, subscription_start, start_date, end_date) as  
     ( select s.account_id 
            , s.subscription_start
            , s.subscription_start::date
            , case when extract(day from s.subscription_start) > 28 
                   then (date_trunc('month', s.subscription_start+interval '2 month' ) - interval '1 day')::date
                   else (date_trunc('month', s.subscription_start+interval '1 month' ) - interval '1 day')::date
              end
         from subscriptions s
       union all
        select b.account_id 
             , b.subscription_start
             , (b.end_date + interval '1 day')::date
             , ((b.end_date + interval '1 day')::date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
         from billing b
        where date_trunc('month',end_date) <= date_trunc('month',now())
     ) 
select * from billing 
order by account_id desc, start_date;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b309b62e5c282a3b5c14a32aee42e34) here. Check difference between Feb 2020 and Feb 2021.